# Source Control в VS Code не отображает измененные файлы и сам репозиторий

Tags: git, github, visual-studio-code

В общем, сама проблема отображена в заголовке. При клонировании репозитория и первых нескольких коммитах все прекрасно работало. После перезагрузки все пропало. Временами появляются "синие часики" рядом с иконкой контроля версий. Git также не подсвечивает сами изменения в файлах. Через терминал сделал коммит-пуш, все отправилось в репозиторий на гитхаб, но хотелось бы все таки видеть работающую систему контроля версий в ВС Код. Благодарю за подсказки и помощь.

Comment: вообще судя по личному наблюдению в vs code vcs система оч плохо работает, либо я ее тоже не смог освоить)) тоже через терминал все делаю в итоге

Comment: @Andrew, по личному наблюдению, во всех IDE плохо работает интеграция с vcs ))

Comment: не ну если так взять то идеально нигде не работает, кроме гит баш)))

Comment: Возможно вы просто выключили auto-save